# Have I implemented an existing design pattern here?

Tags: design-patterns

In my web app, users can input values in a form and send it to the server. The possible input values are stored separately and are imported using AJAX when a user opens the web page. This way, the possible input values can be changed from a central place and dosn't force the developer to change html pages when he has to make modifications. Not only are the input values stored separately, but also other strings, such as button texts, notifications etc. Because of this, I was able to add support for multiple languages.

I have to document this design choice. I think that, in a way, I've implemented the bridge pattern, because I've separated the abstraction from the implementation. Can anyone confirm this? Or have I implemented another design pattern here?

Comment: This sounds like standard internationalization (i18n) or localization practice. Patterns are just ways to name things, and those are the names people will recognize, whether or not they count as "patterns".

Answer (score 2):

> I have to document this design choice.

There is no need to find a pattern that you may or may not have followed. You *have* already documented your choice. It's your first paragraph. Polish that a little bit, save it wherever your company saves this things and go back to work.